# Return value for each element called (accessed) (passed) (traversed) when using the dot notation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy, javascript-proxy

I want to do something like this:

```
let DOM = {
   slide1: {
    button: ".btn",
    box: "#box"
   }
}
```

and then when I write:

```
console.log(DOM.slide1.box);
```

I want the output to be `"#slide1 #box"`.

After some research, I've tried to use the ES6 Proxy object, but the problem wasn't solved this way:

```
const dom_names = {
    slide1: {
        button: ".btn",
        box: "#box"
    }
}
const DOM_handler = {
    get: (target, property, receiver)=>{
        if(property == "slide1") return "#slide1";
        return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    }
}
const DOM = new Proxy(dom_names, DOM_handler);
```

After this implementation, I've recognized that I need to write the following to get the result I'm looking for:

```
console.log(`${DOM.slide1} ${DOM.create.box}) // #slide1 #box
```

As you can see, this is a very bad way, I was thinking of using my solution (using proxies), but the problem is: I need a way to know the "property of the property", I hope you can see and understand what I mean.

Some people will say: use your first implementation (the one without the proxies, meaning the first code in the question) but use `for`..`of` loop to get the key names. I will say, I want to use this exact code:

```
DOM.slide1.box
```

to get this output:

```
"#slide1 #box"
```

Why? why I am doing what I'm doing? Because I need a way to define the HTML classes and IDs in JavaScript, which makes life a lot easier when using `document.querySelector`. Also, the benefit of changing the classes and ID names in the HTML file, so when I change the classes and ID names in the HTML file, I will no longer need to re-factor (re) (rewrite) (change) the newer classes and IDs names inside the whole JavaScript file.

Comment: "I will say I want to use this exact code". This should be a major flag that you shouldn't do this. If the language doesn't support it, trying to hijack the syntax to make it do what you want is always an antipattern. The best case scenario is nobody will understand your code and it'll be unmaintainable. I suggest writing a function that builds the string from the path you want from the object, e.g. `buildPath(DOM, ["slide1", "box"])` or similar. This solves the refactoring concern, although even this design smells a bit without proper motivation for the abstraction.

Comment: As to your second point, if the CSS classes change you still need to change everything in your objects by hand. Also, if you're using ids, a selector like `#slide1 #box` doesn't make much sense. Just say `#box` directly since it's unique--`#slide1` as a parent doesn't add any value to the selector. See [what is the xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It was very easy to say "it's not possible" rather than downvoting the question to the trash of history, some people may be looking for what I'm asking in the future, asking questions when trying and testing is not a shame

Comment: It looks like you're trying to roll your own js templating framework. Have you considered vue or react?

Comment: @Mathew I'm not saying it isn't possible and I'm not trying to shame you, I'm saying even if it is possible, do it at your own risk because it's a very surprising and error-prone adjustment to how object access notation normally operates and likely not the best solution to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Proxies are probably the correct way to do this, but you need to defer producing a string representation until the top-most object has `toString` invoked on it.

Answer (score 2):

While a proxy can do this, there's a much simpler approach: just put the right string values in the properties of `DOM` in the first place. This still allows you to access them like you want:

```
const DOM = selectorHierarchy({
  slide1: {
    button: ".btn",
    box: "#box"
  }
});

function selectorHierarchy(obj, ancestors = []) {
  for (var key in obj)
    if (typeof obj[key] == "string")
      obj[key] = [...ancestors, obj[key]].join(" ");
    else if (typeof obj[key] == "object")
      selectorHierarchy(obj[key], [...ancestors, '#'+key]);
  return obj;
}

console.log(DOM.slide1.box)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is possible. A naive approach is to apply proxies to every object recursively, then pass a private property along with each call, stringifying the traversal to a leaf.

Proof of concept:

```js
const deepProxyAll = (obj, proxyObj) => {
  for (const k in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
      obj[k] = deepProxyAll(obj[k], proxyObj);
    }
  }

  return new Proxy(obj, proxyObj);
};

const proxyObj = {
  get: (target, property, receiver) => {
    if (!target.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      throw new Error(`property '${property}' does not exist on object`);
    }
    else if (typeof target[property] === "object" && 
             typeof target[property] !== "null") {
      target[property]._str = target._str ?
        `${target._str} ${property}` : `#${property}`;
      return target[property];
    }

    return target._str ? `${target._str} ${target[property]}` 
                       : `#${target[property]}`;
  }
};

const obj = {  
  slide1: {
    button: ".btn",
    box: "#box",
    foobar: {bar: {quux: {garply: 42}}}
  },
  test: "hello",
};

const DOM = deepProxyAll(obj, proxyObj);
console.log(DOM.slide1.box);
console.log(DOM.slide1.foobar.bar.quux.garply);
console.log(DOM.test);
```

Proxies are powerful and it's temping to change the behavior of object property access to suit every whim, but think critically about whether the benefits are worth the downsides before adopting this sort of approach as a core design.